# Writing list of lists to csv file without any module/library

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I've the following list of lists:

```
l=[a,b,c,d]
```

where a,b,c,d are separate lists with different data types in each list.

I'm trying to write each list as a separate column to the CSV file with headers as the name of the list.

for ex:

a  b  c  d
1  a \p  t

I've tried the following approach:
converted them to a zip

```
l=zip(a,b,c,d)
```

and writing to CSV file:

```
out = open('out.csv', 'w')
for row in l:
  for column in row:
    out.write('%s,' % column)
      out.write('\n')
```

However, in this case, since one of the lists `b` has text data, the separator, is not working and for that fact any separator being used in `out.write('%s,' % column)` results in the wrong output.

Is there a way to solve this problem without using any modules?

Comment: Can you give the example of list b. Also, have you tried enclosing the data in quotes. e.g. "a", "b", "c"

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow: This is a sample element from the list b:["author": "Bone, Muscle and Joint Team", "published"].  -- since we have comma inside text and the same has been used separator, the text after comma is shifted to next cell in csv

Answer (score 0):

This puts quote marks around each item:

```
for row in i:
  out.write( '"' + '","'.join(row) + '"\n' )
```

However, the built-in `csv` module is smarter, easy to use, and comes for free.